# Rails 6 deploying to Digital Ocean Ubuntu v20 cap production deploy hangs on bundle install

Tags: linux, capistrano, digital-ocean, ruby-on-rails-6, ubuntu-20.04

I am using rails "v6.0.2.2". I am following a [gorails](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/20.04) tutorial to deploy a rails 6  app to a digital ocean droplet using the following gems. Also note I am not using his app from the tutorial I made my own.

- `gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'`
- `gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'`
- `gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'`
- `gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'`

When I run `cap production deploy` it hangs up on,

```
02:47 bundler:install
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet
      01 [DEPRECATED] The `--deployment` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Inst…
      01 [DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead pl…
      01 [DEPRECATED] The `--without` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead…
```

When I click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> the following message prints out:

```
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rack-proxy (0.6.5)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * thor (1.0.1)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * railties (6.0.3.1)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sprockets (4.0.2)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sprockets-rails (3.2.1)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rails (6.0.3.1)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sassc (2.0.1)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * tilt (2.0.10)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sassc-rails (2.1.2)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sass-rails (6.0.0)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * turbolinks-source (5.2.0)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * turbolinks (5.2.1)

 DEBUG [e638babb]        * webpacker (4.2.2)

 DEBUG [e638babb]       Install missing gems with `bundle install`

 DEBUG [e638babb] Finished in 92.342 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

  INFO [6f5e1a04] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet as deploy@138.197.132.192

 DEBUG [6f5e1a04] Command: cd /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet )

 DEBUG [6f5e1a04]       [DEPRECATED] The `--deployment` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set deployment 'true'`, and stop using this flag

 DEBUG [6f5e1a04]       [DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set path '/home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle'`, and stop using this flag

[DEPRECATED] The `--without` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set without 'development test'`, and stop using this flag
```

Below is the cap log file.

```
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO START 2020-06-16 11:47:44 -0400 cap production deploy
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

< I removed some lines to fit it in the question. >

  INFO [68f5d1fe] Finished in 10.386 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [3299d83d] Running if test ! -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/time_buddy/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [3299d83d] Command: if test ! -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/time_buddy/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [3299d83d] Finished in 0.890 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [58d4384f] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 master as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [58d4384f] Command: cd /home/deploy/time_buddy/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-time_buddy-production-main.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 master )
 DEBUG [58d4384f]       8c8ef9f91c6686500f0e39d51f0aa712a684f3dd
 DEBUG [58d4384f] Finished in 2.278 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [79cf963e] Running if test ! -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [79cf963e] Command: if test ! -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [79cf963e] Finished in 0.991 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [f61d8564] Running /usr/bin/env echo "8c8ef9f91c6686500f0e39d51f0aa712a684f3dd" > REVISION as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [f61d8564] Command: cd /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env echo "8c8ef9f91c6686500f0e39d51f0aa712a684f3dd" > REVISION )
  INFO [f61d8564] Finished in 1.166 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [62ab20ce] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919 /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/vendor /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [62ab20ce] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919 /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/vendor /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public )
  INFO [62ab20ce] Finished in 1.349 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [5c936b1a] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/log ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [5c936b1a] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/log ]
 DEBUG [5c936b1a] Finished in 0.838 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [aa93a1db] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/log ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [aa93a1db] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/log ]
 DEBUG [aa93a1db] Finished in 0.991 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [aaae6088] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/log as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [aaae6088] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/log )
  INFO [aaae6088] Finished in 0.719 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [54ac93bd] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/log /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/log as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [54ac93bd] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/log /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/log )
  INFO [54ac93bd] Finished in 1.419 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [f21c51b7] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/pids ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [f21c51b7] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/pids ]
 DEBUG [f21c51b7] Finished in 0.821 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [18b57d00] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/pids ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [18b57d00] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/pids ]
 DEBUG [18b57d00] Finished in 1.270 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [beccc8d6] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/tmp/pids /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/pids as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [beccc8d6] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/tmp/pids /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/pids )
  INFO [beccc8d6] Finished in 1.058 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [1b69c567] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/cache ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [1b69c567] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/cache ]
 DEBUG [1b69c567] Finished in 0.769 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [e099bc9c] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/cache ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [e099bc9c] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/cache ]
 DEBUG [e099bc9c] Finished in 1.149 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [1d0d139a] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/tmp/cache /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/cache as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [1d0d139a] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/tmp/cache /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/cache )
  INFO [1d0d139a] Finished in 1.789 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [7b52e3bd] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/sockets ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [7b52e3bd] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/sockets ]
 DEBUG [7b52e3bd] Finished in 1.308 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [c60cad34] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/sockets ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [c60cad34] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/sockets ]
 DEBUG [c60cad34] Finished in 1.234 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [3e5aef7e] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/sockets as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [3e5aef7e] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/tmp/sockets )
  INFO [3e5aef7e] Finished in 1.357 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [527c2dc2] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/vendor/bundle ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [527c2dc2] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/vendor/bundle ]
 DEBUG [527c2dc2] Finished in 1.089 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [75aba25c] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/vendor/bundle ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [75aba25c] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/vendor/bundle ]
 DEBUG [75aba25c] Finished in 1.510 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [ff36386a] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/vendor/bundle /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/vendor/bundle as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [ff36386a] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/vendor/bundle /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/vendor/bundle )
  INFO [ff36386a] Finished in 1.112 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [0907129d] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/.bundle ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [0907129d] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/.bundle ]
 DEBUG [0907129d] Finished in 0.997 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [f0778333] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/.bundle ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [f0778333] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/.bundle ]
 DEBUG [f0778333] Finished in 0.506 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [97ac7400] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/.bundle /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/.bundle as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [97ac7400] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/.bundle /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/.bundle )
  INFO [97ac7400] Finished in 0.531 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [3391a2a3] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/system ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [3391a2a3] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/system ]
 DEBUG [3391a2a3] Finished in 1.279 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [5f783633] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/system ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [5f783633] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/system ]
 DEBUG [5f783633] Finished in 0.254 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [cf1d5fbe] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/public/system /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/system as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [cf1d5fbe] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/public/system /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/system )
  INFO [cf1d5fbe] Finished in 1.141 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [93787cba] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/uploads ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [93787cba] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/uploads ]
 DEBUG [93787cba] Finished in 1.174 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [8daa511f] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/uploads ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [8daa511f] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/uploads ]
 DEBUG [8daa511f] Finished in 0.332 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [db068d9d] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/public/uploads /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/uploads as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [db068d9d] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/public/uploads /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/uploads )
  INFO [db068d9d] Finished in 0.538 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [25967304] Running [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/assets ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [25967304] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/assets ]
 DEBUG [25967304] Finished in 0.369 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [e2970df8] Running [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/assets ] as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [e2970df8] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/assets ]
 DEBUG [e2970df8] Finished in 0.725 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [24fbba0d] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/assets as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [24fbba0d] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919/public/assets )
  INFO [24fbba0d] Finished in 1.101 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e8b2b6ba] Running if test ! -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [e8b2b6ba] Command: if test ! -d /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [e8b2b6ba] Finished in 0.545 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e638babb] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle check --path /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [e638babb] Command: cd /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle check --path /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle )
 DEBUG [e638babb]       [DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set path '/home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle'`, and stop using this flag
 DEBUG [e638babb]       The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
 DEBUG [e638babb]       The following gems are missing
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rake (13.0.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * i18n (1.8.3)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * minitest (5.14.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * thread_safe (0.3.6)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * tzinfo (1.2.7)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * zeitwerk (2.3.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * activesupport (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * builder (3.2.4)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * erubi (1.9.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * nokogiri (1.10.9)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * crass (1.0.6)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * loofah (2.5.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * actionview (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rack (2.2.3)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rack-test (1.1.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * actionpack (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * nio4r (2.5.2)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * websocket-driver (0.7.2)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * actioncable (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * globalid (0.4.2)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * activejob (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * activemodel (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * activerecord (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * mimemagic (0.3.5)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * marcel (0.3.3)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * activestorage (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * mini_mime (1.0.2)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * mail (2.7.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * actionmailbox (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * actionmailer (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * actiontext (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * net-ssh (6.1.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * net-scp (3.0.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sshkit (1.21.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * airbrussh (1.4.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * msgpack (1.3.3)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * bootsnap (1.4.6)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * capistrano (3.14.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * capistrano-bundler (1.6.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * capistrano-passenger (0.2.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * capistrano-rails (1.5.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * capistrano-rbenv (2.1.6)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * ffi (1.13.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * jbuilder (2.10.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * method_source (1.0.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * mysql2 (0.5.3)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * puma (4.3.5)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rack-proxy (0.6.5)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * thor (1.0.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * railties (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sprockets (4.0.2)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * rails (6.0.3.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sassc (2.0.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * tilt (2.0.10)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sassc-rails (2.1.2)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * sass-rails (6.0.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * turbolinks (5.2.1)
 DEBUG [e638babb]        * webpacker (4.2.2)
 DEBUG [e638babb]       Install missing gems with `bundle install`
 DEBUG [e638babb] Finished in 92.342 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [6f5e1a04] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet as deploy@138.197.132.192
 DEBUG [6f5e1a04] Command: cd /home/deploy/time_buddy/releases/20200616154919 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet )
 DEBUG [6f5e1a04]       [DEPRECATED] The `--deployment` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set deployment 'true'`, and stop using this flag
 DEBUG [6f5e1a04]       [DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set path '/home/deploy/time_buddy/shared/bundle'`, and stop using this flag
[DEPRECATED] The `--without` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set without 'development test'`, and stop using this flag
main@Stevens-MacBook-Air time_buddy %
```

I think it has something to do with the gem `gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'`

Here is my gem file,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.2'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated kinda stuck on this. Not sure if this helps but i'll include the g++ and gcc versions i have below. Thanks in advance!

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I saw some similar questions but they didn't fix my issue. I am on chapter 5 deploying. Where he runs the `cap production deploy` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues in the past deploying apps in small servers (5usd DO droplets, nano EC2). Those servers have little resources, and some heavy operations (installing nodejs, running bundle install) hit some problems. Try adding swap space to your droplet. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will give this a try and get back to you. :)